# Github pages made with create-react-app + react-routers doesn't load in iOS devices

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages, pageload

I just finished working on a website project and shared it with some people for them to try, website doesn't render at all in the iOS device, but I can't locale the issue since I don't "own" an iOS device.

I am aware of browserstack but it doesn't help me more than seeing the page not loading with my own eyes.

iOS blank page load screenshot [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/927702904779993090/930588507456536646/IMG_4026.png) ( Tried with both safari and google chrome, same issue on iPhone X and 11 Pro )

You can see the project [here](https://enesceylan.github.io/mythic-companion/#/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue:

Problem was that Chrome, Firefox and Safari on iOS devices do not use regexp lookbehind.

replaced: `const linkParam = document.URL.match(/(?<=team-builder/).+/g);`

with:

```
const urlSplit = document.URL.split('/');
const linkParam = urlSplit[urlSplit.findIndex((param) => param === 'team-builder') + 1];
```